# How to store data for Windows App's

Tags: c#, windows, storage

I'm not familiar with App development therefore I do not know where to start.

I need to store data locally for a Windows Phone Application, however i do not know where to go about doing this..

Is storing data locally like storing data in an SQL database such as MySQLWorkbench for example does it use SQL queries to insert and retrieve data?

Where is the local database? and how does it work? Does every windows phone have a universal database which all apps share? or does it have a separate database for each app?

I've been searching Google on how to go about doing this for days now and I can't find anything useful, if anyone has any useful tutorials that would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the data? Application settins or hundreds of data records.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have built-in local database in Windows Phone/Windows apps. 
You can store data in local storage. This isn't database - you can store json files etc.

Read this: [http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/6d1860/how-to-implement-local-storage-in-universal-windows-apps/](https://dzone.com/articles/using-local-storage-windows) for Windows Universal Apps
or this: https://dzone.com/articles/using-local-storage-windows for Windows Phone Silverlight

You have one storage per app, but if you're developing Windows Universal Apps you can have shared storage between Windows Phone and Windows Desktop app.
Read about [Roaming Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx)